# how to alter mysql database table when another table in the same database is altered?

Tags: mysql, database

i have 2 scripts running on my website. each do a certain function but they both have it is own profile table in the database. i want to use only one profile table for both scripts.

the 2 tables is not identical for example:

```
table_profile_1
--user_id
--websiteurl
--name
--username
--twitter
--facebook

table_profile_2
--id
--name
--username
--website
--twitter
--facebooklink
--avatarurl
```

lets say i am going to use table_profile_2 as the default profile. is there is anyway i can connect both tables so when the table_profile_2 is updated, the table_profile_1 is updated too.

i want this because the function of both scripts needs the profile tables. i thought i can create a new table and change all sql queries table_profile_2 and table_profile_1 into my custom table but this didnt work because both tables are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MySQL Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).Whenever `table_profile_2` is updated, you can fire a trigger to update `table_profile_1`. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) is a link which shows the syntax and tutorial on how to setup triggers.

Alternately, if the two tables need not be in sync in real-time, you can setup a nightly batch job which syncs the data from table_2 to table_1

Note: Triggers are only available from MySQL 5.0.